# Querying JSONB fields with joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a database with two tables. One containing events & the other containing attendees for those events. Theses events have a jsonb field containing an array of objects with a `"duration"` attribute

**events**

| id | name | occurrences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "The Great Beyond" | [{"duration": 100}, {"duration": 200}, {"duration": 300}] |
| 2 | "The Final Countdown" | [{"duration": 50}] |
| 3 | "The Next Plain" | null |

**attendees**

| id | name | event_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Bob" | 1 |
| 2 | "Susan" | 2 |
| 3 | "Terry" | 3 |

I want to run a single query to pull data about these events & showcase the name of the event, how many people are attending & what the current "duration" is for each event (by summing up all the `duration` values in the `occurrences` column.

The current query I use is resulting in incorrect `COUNT` values for my attendees. I suspect it has to do with the way I am constructing my `JOIN`s such that additional rows are being created.

```sql
SELECT
  events.id AS "ID",
  events.name AS "Name",
  SUM(coalesce(occurrences_arry->'duration', '0'):int) as "Duration",
  COUNT(attendees.*) as "Attendees"
FROM
  events
    INNER JOIN attendees on attendees.event_id = events.id
    LEFT JOIN jsonb_array_elements(events.occurrences) as occurrences_arry on true
GROUP BY events.id
```

The result I get back has too high of a count for "Attendees" (The last record should have 1 attendees but says 3). I am pretty sure it has to do with the `INNER JOIN` `LEFT JOIN` combo I am using so that I can utilize `jsonb_array_elements`. Every time a new occurrence is added the attendees count grows ‍

| ID | Name | Duration | Attendees |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | "The Final Countdown" | 50 | 1 |
| 3 | "The Next Plain" | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | "The Great Beyond" | 600 | 3 |

How can I best perform an `INNER JOIN` on my attendees table and ALSO sum up all the `duration`s in for each event?

Comment: You've tagged two different RDBMS, do you not know which platform you are using?

Comment: [JSONB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) is a data type used by PostgreSQL. MySQL has only JSON.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't not mean to tag mysql. This has been fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the duration in a subquery. You have most of the code that is needed already, you just have to move it, example:

```
SELECT
  events.id AS "ID",
  events.name AS "Name",
  (SELECT coalesce(SUM((occurrences_arry->>'duration')::int), 0)
   FROM jsonb_array_elements(events.occurrences) as occurrences_arry) as "Duration",
  COUNT(attendees.*) as "Attendees"
FROM
  events
    INNER JOIN attendees on attendees.event_id = events.id
GROUP BY events.id
```

A `SUM` returns null, if there are no rows, hence I used `coalesce` to default to 0 in this case.

Comment: You can temporarily [play with it in a sandbox](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/03e9e/10).

Comment: Thankyou, I knew I was over-thinking this!